# Comparing 2 Word Documents of Different Length

Tags: c#, ms-word, diff, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to compare 2 word documents. My goal is to get a list that has each line from both files and whether or not they match. I have that part working. My problem is if one file is larger than the other, the text from the larger one doesn't get added to the list mentioned above. There are cases were one document could be larger than the other. It's for a document revision system. The current revision may have more text in it than the previous or vice versa.

So far, I have this code. I modified the example found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/07/05/comparing-two-open-xml-documents-using-the-zip-extension-method.aspx).

Here are the two sample files I've been using (word documents)
Test1.docx:

```
Test

This is a test document. It was created May 31.
The contents of this document are:
Unknown
```

Test2.docx:

```
Test

This is a test document. It was created Apr 1.
The contents of this document are:
Test Item 1
Test Item 2
```

Here is my Program.cs file, this is where I edited. In the CompareDocuments method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace DocxDiff
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static List<DocumentCompare> _differences = new List<DocumentCompare>();

        public static string GetParagraphText(XElement p)
        {
            return p.Descendants(W.r)
                .Where(e => e.Parent.Name != W.del && e.Parent.Name != W.moveFrom)
                .Descendants(W.t)
                .Select(t => (string) t)
                .StringConcatenate();
        }

        public static List<DocumentCompare> CompareDocuments(WordprocessingDocument doc1, WordprocessingDocument doc2)
        {
            XDocument xDoc1 = doc1.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
            XDocument xDoc2 = doc2.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

            var doc1Elements = xDoc1
                .Descendants()
                .Where(e => e.Name != W.commentRangeStart
                            && e.Name != W.commentRangeEnd
                            && e.Name != W.proofErr
                            && !e.Ancestors(W.p).Any());
            var doc2Elements = xDoc2
                .Descendants()
                .Where(e => e.Name != W.commentRangeStart
                            && e.Name != W.commentRangeEnd
                            && e.Name != W.proofErr
                            && !e.Ancestors(W.p).Any());

            List<DocumentCompare> differences = new List<DocumentCompare>();

            IEnumerable<bool> correspondingElementEquivalency = doc1Elements.Zip(doc2Elements, (e1, e2) =>
            {
                // if the lines are different, set to true
                bool difference = false;
                if (e1.Name != e2.Name)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (e1.Name == W.p && e2.Name == W.p)
                {
                    if ((GetParagraphText(e1) != GetParagraphText(e2)))
                    {
                        // there is a difference between the documents
                        difference = true;
                    }

                    // record lines
                    differences.Add(new DocumentCompare() { Document1Text = e1.Value, Document2Text = e2.Value, Difference = difference });
                }

                // this is from the code in the link above
                // this method does not return a bool, it returns the list of differences
                return true;
            });

            // determine if the documents are equivalent
            // this has to be here to run the code above
            bool test = correspondingElementEquivalency.Any(e => e != true);

            return differences;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc1Path = @"C:\Diff\Test1.docx";
            var doc2Path = @"C:\Diff\Test2.docx";

            using(WordprocessingDocument doc1 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(doc1Path, false))
            using(WordprocessingDocument doc2 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(doc2Path, false))
            {
                _differences = CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2);

                foreach (var t in _differences)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Difference: {0}\nDoc 1: {1}\nDoc 2: {2}", t.Difference, t.Document1Text, t.Document2Text);
                }
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class for storing the compared documents:

```
public class DocumentCompare
{
    public string Document1Text { get; set; }
    public string Document2Text { get; set; }
    public bool Difference { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Extensions.cs file (from the tutorial, not modified):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace DocxDiff
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static XDocument GetXDocument(this OpenXmlPart part)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = part.Annotation<XDocument>();

            if (xdoc != null)
                return xdoc;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(part.GetStream()))
                xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(streamReader));

            part.AddAnnotation(xdoc);
            return xdoc;
        }

        public static string StringConcatenate(this IEnumerable<string> source)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var s in source)
                sb.Append(s);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> func)
        {
            var ie1 = first.GetEnumerator();
            var ie2 = second.GetEnumerator();

            while (ie1.MoveNext() && ie2.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return func(ie1.Current, ie2.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the W.cs class that the tutorial also gave:

```
public static class W
{
    public static XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

    public static XName p = w + "p";
    public static XName r = w + "r";
    public static XName t = w + "t";
    public static XName commentRangeStart = w + "commentRangeStart";
    public static XName commentRangeEnd = w + "commentRangeEnd";
    public static XName proofErr = w + "proofErr";
    public static XName del = w + "del";
    public static XName moveFrom = w + "moveFrom";
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm pretty sure I need to modify the Zip method to add in the lines in the larger file and add in an empty string for the other file. I tried (unsuccessfully) to modify this to work (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190657/add-two-lists-of-different-length-in-c-sharp)):

```
static void Main() {
    var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var b = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    foreach (var c in a.Merge(b, (x, y) => x + y)) {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
        IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, T> operation) {
    using (var iter1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var iter2 = second.GetEnumerator()) {
        while (iter1.MoveNext()) {
            if (iter2.MoveNext()) {
                yield return operation(iter1.Current, iter2.Current);
            } else {
                yield return iter1.Current;
            }
        }
        while (iter2.MoveNext()) {
            yield return iter2.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I have to do something like that. Merge the documents. Somehow I need to add an empty list item to the smaller document.

**EDIT:** This is what I just came up with, it sort of works, only It won't show items in the documents that are in lists (word lists). I put it in the DocumentCompare method in Program.cs right after `bool test...` and before `return differences;`:

```
// get document sizes
        var largerDoc = doc1Elements.Count() > doc2Elements.Count() && doc1Elements.Count() != doc2Elements.Count() ? doc1Elements : doc2Elements;
        var smallerDocCount = doc1Elements.Count() < doc2Elements.Count() && doc1Elements.Count() != doc2Elements.Count() ? doc1Elements.Count() : doc2Elements.Count();
        var doc1Larger = doc1Elements.Count() > doc2Elements.Count() && doc1Elements.Count() != doc2Elements.Count() ? true : false;
        var doc1Arr = doc1Elements.ToArray();
        var doc2Arr = doc2Elements.ToArray();

        // add in the remaining text for the larger document
        for (var i = smallerDocCount; i < largerDoc.Count(); i++)
        {
            // if doc1 is larger, add doc 1 and null for doc 2
            if (doc1Larger)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("doc1 Text: {0}", doc1Arr[i].Value);
                differences.Add(new DocumentComparison() { Document1Text = doc1Arr[i].Value, Document2Text = "", Difference = true });
            }
            else if(!doc1Larger) {
                Console.WriteLine("doc2 Text: {0}", doc2Arr[i].Value);
                differences.Add(new DocumentComparison() { Document1Text = "", Document2Text = doc2Arr[i].Value, Difference = true });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I've come up with. (It may not be the most efficient but I believe it's a fine solution for this project). Here's the code (explanation below):

```
public static List<DocumentCompare> CompareDocuments(WordprocessingDocument doc1, WordprocessingDocument doc2)
    {
        XDocument xDoc1 = doc1.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
        XDocument xDoc2 = doc2.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();

        // these queries return the elements that contain text in the word documents
        var doc1Elements = xDoc1
            .Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name != W.commentRangeStart
                        && e.Name != W.commentRangeEnd
                        && e.Name != W.proofErr
                        && !e.Ancestors(W.p).Any());
        var doc2Elements = xDoc2
            .Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name != W.commentRangeStart
                        && e.Name != W.commentRangeEnd
                        && e.Name != W.proofErr
                        && !e.Ancestors(W.p).Any());

        List<DocumentCompare> differences = new List<DocumentCompare>();

        IEnumerable<bool> correspondingElementEquivalency = doc1Elements.Zip(doc2Elements, (e1, e2) =>
        {
            bool difference = false;
            if (e1.Name != e2.Name)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (e1.Name == W.p && e2.Name == W.p)
            {
                // e1.Name == W.p && 
                if ((GetParagraphText(e1) != GetParagraphText(e2)))
                {
                    // there is a difference between the documents
                    difference = true;
                }

                // record lines
                differences.Add(new DocumentCompare() { Document1Text = e1.Value, Document2Text = e2.Value, Difference = difference });
            }
            return true;
        });

        // determine if the documents are equivalent
        bool test = correspondingElementEquivalency.Any(e => e != true);

        var doc1Values = (from ie1 in doc1Elements where ie1.Name == W.p select ie1.Value).ToList();
        var doc2Values = (from ie2 in doc2Elements where ie2.Name == W.p select ie2.Value).ToList();

        // determine the larger document to add the remainder of that document to the list
        var largerDoc = doc1Values.Count() > doc2Values.Count() && doc1Values.Count() != doc2Values.Count() ? doc1Values : doc2Values;
        var smallerDocCount = doc1Values.Count() < doc2Values.Count() && doc1Values.Count() != doc2Values.Count() ? doc1Values.Count() : doc2Values.Count();
        var doc1Larger = doc1Values.Count() > doc2Values.Count() && doc1Values.Count() != doc2Values.Count() ? true : false;
        var doc1Arr = doc1Values.ToArray();
        var doc2Arr = doc2Values.ToArray();

        // add in the remaining text for the larger document
        for (var i = smallerDocCount; i < largerDoc.Count(); i++)
        {
            // if doc1 is larger, add doc 1 and null for doc 2
            if (doc1Larger)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("doc1 Text: {0}", doc1Arr[i]);
                differences.Add(new DocumentCompare() { Document1Text = doc1Arr[i], Document2Text = "", Difference = true });
            }
            else if(!doc1Larger) {
                Console.WriteLine("doc2 Text: {0}", doc2Arr[i]);
                differences.Add(new DocumentCompare() { Document1Text = "", Document2Text = doc2Arr[i], Difference = true });
            }
        }

        return differences;
    }
```

Okay, so, the IEnumerable finishes up to the point where the smallest document ends. Then, I get the rest of the larger document (starting from the end of the smaller one) and just append it to the ending of the list. I still need to tighten up some of the code but it works.