# LINQ Zip all elements

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way utilize [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx), where all elements in both `IEnumerable`s are used? If the `IEnumerable`s have different counts, default remaining merges to `default(T)`.

---

**Examples**

```
var first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var second = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
var zipped = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => new { f, s });
// actual:    [ {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"} ]
// expecting: [ {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {4, null}, {5, null} ]

var first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var second = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var zipped = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => new { f, s });
// actual:    [ {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"} ]
// expecting: [ {1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}, {0, "d"}, {0, "e"} ]
```

Comment: IMHO it would be much easier to roll your own extension method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can create your custom `Zip` extension method:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Zip<T1, T2, T>(this IEnumerable<T1> first,
                                    IEnumerable<T2> second, Func<T1, T2, T> operation)
{
    using (var iter1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var iter2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iter1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (iter2.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return operation(iter1.Current, iter2.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return operation(iter1.Current, default(T2));
            }
        }
        while (iter2.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return operation(default(T1), iter2.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea was taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190657/add-two-lists-of-different-length-in-c-sharp/1241495) answer. You can test it in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DCjZlY) if you want

Comment: This works great but please correct me if I'm wrong, shouldn't the name of this extension method be different than Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>, given this is the same signature as the original System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip method? ZipLongest for example?

Comment: Tip: In new version of linq, the `Zip` will return a `ValueTuple`, you can remove `operation` param.

Answer (score 5):

Try MoreLinq's [ZipLongest](https://morelinq.github.io/2.4/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ZipLongest__3.htm) method:

> If the two input sequences are of different lengths then the result
>   sequence will always be as long as the longer of the two input
>   sequences. The default value of the shorter sequence element type is
>   used for padding. This operator uses deferred execution and streams
>   its results.

Answer (score 1):

If you use System.Interactive and EnumerableEx, and as long as you know which sequence is longer, you could do this:

```
var first = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var second = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }.Concat(EnumerableEx.Repeat((string)null));
var zipped = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => new { f, s });
```