# Join 2 lists have different length by in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can I join 2 lists of different lengths. it should join with the sequence.
Eg.

```
{1,2,3,4} with {5,6,7}
```

I need to get result like below.

```
{{1,5}, {2,6}, {3,7}, {4,null}}
```

I tried this.

```
var qry = a.Select((i, index) => new {i, j = b[index]});
```

But its throwing error since the lists are having different lengths.
Please help me to get the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add two Lists of different length in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190657/add-two-lists-of-different-length-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you using Lists or IEnumerables?

Comment: Pure Linq implementation will be very inefficient. Just write a custom Zip operation.

Comment: I am using Lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var a = new int?[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var b = new int?[] { 5, 6, 7 };

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(a.Count(), b.Count()))
                       .Select(n => new[] {a.ElementAtOrDefault(n), b.ElementAtOrDefault(n)});
```

Do note the `?` in the array declarations. That is necessary in order to have null values in the resulting list. Omitting the `?` causes the result to have 0 instead of `null`.

If you can't or don't want to declare the arrays as `int?`, then you'll have to do the cast in the Select like so:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(a.Count(), b.Count()))
                       .Select(n => new[] { a.Select(i => (int?)i).ElementAtOrDefault(n), b.Select(i => (int?)i).ElementAtOrDefault(n) });
```

This second bit of code will work correctly with regular `int` arrays or Lists.

Comment: why you've cast `a` and `b` `var`?

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Technically it would work for any `IEnumerable<T>`, but it will just be *super* inefficient for any `IEnumerable<T>` that's not also an `IList<T>` (the OP says they have lists, but this is rather dangerous in that the functional requirement on these being lists isn't obvious).

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much @stybl

Answer (score 2):

The ugly but working version is the following:

```
a.Cast<int?>().Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<int?>(null, Math.Max(b.Count() - a.Count(), 0)))
    .Zip(b.Cast<int?>()
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<int?>(null, Math.Max(a.Count() - b.Count(), 0))),
        (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

Its drawback it double evaluation of a collection (the first one is by calling `.Count()`).

So it is better just to write an extension

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipNull<T1, T2, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T1> a, IEnumerable<T2> b, Func<T1?, T2?, TResult> func)
    where T1 : struct
    where T2 : struct
{
    using (var it1 = a.GetEnumerator())
    using (var it2 = b.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (it1.MoveNext())
            {
                if (it2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return func(it1.Current, it2.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return func(it1.Current, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (it2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return func(null, it2.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
a.ZipNull(b, (x, y) => new { x, y });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is effectively a `Zip`, but where it zips to the end of the longer, rather than the shorter, of the two sequences.  You can write such a `Zip` method, with something that looks a bit similar to the actual Zip implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipAll<TSource, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> other,
    Func<TSource, TSecond, TResult> projection)
{
    using (var firstIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondIterator = other.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool hasFirst = firstIterator.MoveNext();
            bool hasSecond = secondIterator.MoveNext();
            TSource first = hasFirst ? firstIterator.Current : default(TSource);
            TSecond second = hasSecond ? secondIterator.Current : default(TSecond);
            if (hasFirst || hasSecond)
                yield return projection(first, second);
            else
                yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

With that you can write:

```
a.ZipAll(b, (i, j) => new { i, j });
```

You could make the code a bit shorter by requiring the inputs to be lists, but the code wouldn't be any faster as lists, just less typing, and it's not like it's *that* much extra work to support *any* sequence, so I'd say it's worth the added few lines of code.

Comment: Hi many thanks for this input, is it possible to do with the three lists and i am looking for three lists with different structure and placing null as well

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.ToList();
var y = new[] { 5, 6, 7 }.ToList();
var arrayLists = new[] {x, y}.OrderBy(t => t.Count).ToList();
var result = arrayLists
            .Last()
            .Select((item, i) => new[] { x[i], i < arrayLists.First().Count ? y[i] : (int?)null })
            .ToList();
```

this should work for any IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through the lists and construct new, let's say `Dictionary<int?, int?>` out of each list element:

```
var theFirstList = new List<int?> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var theSecondList = new List<int?> { 5, 6, 7 };

var el = new Dictionary<int?, int?>();

var length = Math.Max(theFirstList.Count, theSecondList.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    el.Add(theFirstList.ElementAtOrDefault(i), theSecondList.ElementAtOrDefault(i));
}
```