# LINQ Except sends first collection's items to IEqualityComparer Equals method

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` in order to use `Except` with complex typed collections. I've encountered with a strange (or a usual thing that I don't know) issue while debugging. I have two collections with different counts of items like below.

`{A, B, C, D, E}.Except({A, B}, new CustomComparer()).ToList()`

By adding `ToList()` I'm able to debug overriden `Equals(x, y)`. It works like expected until item `C` After item `B`, Except sends `C` and `D` to the `Equals(x, y)` so I cannot distinguish that these elements belong to first collection or one of them belong to second one.

Here below my IEqualityComparer implementation. DifferenceHighlighter is the callback method provides me to collect differences at caller location.

```
public SubmoduleListComparer(
  Action<FormerGsdmlComparison.SubModuleListDifferenceContainer, string, string> callBack, 
  string firstFileName, 
  string secondFilename)
    {
        DifferenceHighlighter = callBack;
        m_FirstFileName = firstFileName;
        m_SecondFileName = secondFilename;
    }    

public bool Equals(Submodule x, Submodule y)
{
        bool areEqual = true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        var submoduleDifferences = new FormerGsdmlComparison.SubModuleListDifferenceContainer
        {
            file1 = new FormerGsdmlComparison.Submodule
            {
                orderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
                submoduleId = x.Id,
                submoduleIdentNumber = x.SubmoduleIdentNumber
            }
        };

        if (x.Id != y.Id)
        {
            submoduleDifferences.file2.submoduleId = y.Id;
            areEqual = false;
        }
        if (x.OrderNumber != y.OrderNumber)
        {
            submoduleDifferences.file2.orderNumber = y.OrderNumber;
            areEqual = false;
        }
        if (x.SubmoduleIdentNumber != y.SubmoduleIdentNumber)
        {
            submoduleDifferences.file2.submoduleIdentNumber = y.SubmoduleIdentNumber;
            areEqual = false;
        }

        if (!areEqual)
        {
            DifferenceHighlighter(submoduleDifferences, m_FirstFileName, m_SecondFileName);
        }

        return areEqual;
    }
```

As I've mentioned above; I was expecting that `Except()` sends `null` when iteration on second collection's items over. Instead, it sends two elements from first collection to `Equals(x, y)` Is that the default behavior of LINQ Except and I should do more checks or am I missing something ?

**EDIT**

`first` collection contains 51 elements and `second` one contains only 7 elements. After sending 7 items to Equals(x, y) from both collections; Except starts to send sequential items from `first` collection. For example:

[This is the debug view for first items on both collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI6FB.png)

Above one is exactly what I'm expecting. First two items fell into Equals method. But after 7th iteration; [items on `Equals(x, y)` like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIDF6.png).

`second` collection does not have these items. Above items are 8th and 9th elements of `first` collection. So my DifferenceHighlighter assumes that these are differences between two collections.

Comment: `Except` returns *distinct* items only, e.g. `new int[] {1, 1}.Except(new int[0] ).ToList();` will return `[1]`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] where the sample inputs are defined **in code**.

Comment: What the LINQ method in question is doing doesn't really matter. `IEqualityComparer<T>` is not supposed to be used this way. All it is supposed to do is to return if passed `x` and `y` are equal - where they come from is undefined.

Comment: "I was expecting that Except() sends null" - I'm curious why you were expecting this? You don't have a null in either of the sets so why are you expecting it to be comparing something to null?

Comment: @Chris I've thought that when second collection are out of items; Except() continues to send items from first collection and null as an element of second collection.

Comment: @KeremKambur: It would appear then that you have a very incorrect view of what Except does. What it does is return you all the items in the first set that aren't in the second. The order doesn't matter at all. (ie all of Set 1 Except those in set 2). So `{A, B, C, D, E}.Except({A, B}` would be the same as `{E, B, C, D, A}.Except({B, A}`. In practice what it does is loops through the first set and outputs the value if it hasn't already been outputted and if it isn't in the second set (as you can see in Dmitry's answer).

Comment: If you want to compare things that are in the same positions in your collections then you may want to look at `Enumerable.Zip` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DOTNET/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2). This will match the first items together and then the second, and so on until one collection runs out. No idea if its helpful for you but thought it might be of interest...

Comment: @Chris thank you for mentioning out `Enumerable.Zip` solution. It actually quite fits to my terms of comparison.

Comment: Glad I managed to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the *expected* behaviour; `Except` operates with *set*s (not *bags*) which contain uinque items only; so `Except` returns *distinct* items only:

```
var demo = new int[] {1, 1} 
  .Except(new int[0])
  .ToList();

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", demo));
```

Outcome:

```
1
```

In your case, `Except` tests items `C` and `D` (*both* from the 1st collection) in that very purpose: to ensure to return *distinct* items only:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptIterator<TSource>(
  IEnumerable<TSource> first, 
  IEnumerable<TSource> second, 
  IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);

    foreach (TSource element in second) 
        set.Add(element);

    foreach (TSource element in first)
        // Here Except tries adding element from first 
        // and have to compare if the element has been in set already.
        // in your case 'D' will be tested on A, B (which are in second)
        // and 'C' which has been added earlier
        if (set.Add(element)) 
            yield return element;
}
```

If you want "*all* items in `first` (duplicates *included*) except those which *appear* in `second`" you can create `HashSet<T>` manually and put a simple `Where`:

```
 var second = new MyType[] {A, B}; // or whatever IEnumerable<MyType>

 ...

 // Items to exclude
 HashSet<MyType> exclude = new HashSet<MyType>(second, new CustomComparer());

 var result = first // {A, B, C, D, E}
   .Where(item => !exclude.Contains(item)) // all items but appear in exclude - i.e. second
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I've completely misunderstood the purpose and usage of `Except()`. As Chris' comments and Dmitry's answer on explanation of `Except()`, it's better to use `Zip()` to iterate over two collections, detect differences and merge results in another collection (or other countless options). `Except` really does what it means. After a quick investigation over `Zip()` simple code example which also fits my condition like below:

```
foreach (var submoduleListPairs in firstFile.SubmoduleList.Zip(secondFile.SubmoduleList, (x, y) => new { x, y }))
{
    if (submoduleListPairs.x != null && submoduleListPairs.y != null)
    {
        if (submoduleListPairs.x.SubmoduleIdentNumber != submoduleListPairs.y.SubmoduleIdentNumber)
        {
            //Add differences to result collection
        }
        //Do other comparisons like below
    }
    else if (submoduleListPairs.x == null)
    {
        //Notate that second collection contains an item which first one not on result collection
    }
    else if (submoduleListPairs.y == null)
    {
        //Notate that first collection contains an item which second one not on result collection 
    }
}
```

It might not the best usage of `Zip()` but I'd like to show how it solves my problem and why should I not use `Except()` for comparison purposes. I think I've stucked on an idea that IEqualityComparer and Except are the LINQ way of comparison problems.

**LAST EDIT**

`Zip()` idea was inspiring but built-in `Zip()`stops if one of collection is out of item because of its purpose (merging collections). So I've made another deeper search and found this great SO question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551229/7273196). Even it has no upvotes, it's a great simplification of above answers.