# how to merge two csv files with different columns and rows in c#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-core

I'm trying to merge two csv files which have different headers and different number of rows/lines.
Using the following code, but doesn't get correct output. It's working when rows are same.

```
var first = File.ReadAllLines("firstfile.csv");
var second = File.ReadAllLines("secondfile.csv");
var result = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => string.Join(",", f, s));
File.WriteAllLines("combined.csv", result);
```

for ex:
firstfile is

```
col1,colb,colc
a,b,c
a,v,f
```

the secondfile is

```
colx,coly
x,y
cc,aa
bb,vv
m,n
```

the output is get

```
col1,colb,colc,colx,coly
a,b,c,x,y
a,v,f,cc,aa
```

the second file rows are missiing.
my expected output is

```
col1,colb,colc,colx,coly
a,b,c,x,y
a,v,f,cc,aa
,,,bb,vv
,,,m,n
```

Comment: If you have different headers then what is the "correct" output?

Comment: how would you work out which line from file1 goes with which line on file2

Comment: If I assume correctly what your end goal is, you'll have to provide data for the rows missing in the "shorter" file, and for that you need to count the number of columns in it. Rewrite your code to plain old `for` loops and you'll probably get an idea of what to do next (or at least an idea for a more specific question).

Comment: You maybe also want to check out [Linq Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) if you're trying to *join* the two tables (if that is what you mean by merge).

Comment: question update with example

Comment: can you add in an extra step that checks the rows in each file and for the file with less rows, append blank entries. That way when you merge they'll marry up correctly. I'd say the current merge is hitting the 'null' rows and is stopping or this is nulling the entire merged row in the final file.

Comment: `Enumerable.Zip` merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them and ignores the extra rows. You can read more in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method that allows you to merge two lists of unequal length.  `Zip` only merges down to the shortest length.   However, you can achieve what you want by modifying Marc Gravell's excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190657/add-two-lists-of-different-length-in-c-sharp), in order to allow a default value.  Create yourself an extensions class, something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
    IEnumerable<T> second, T defaultValue, Func<T, T, T> operation)
    {
        using (var iter1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (var iter2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (iter1.MoveNext())
            {
                if (iter2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return operation(iter1.Current, iter2.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return operation(iter1.Current, defaultValue);
                }
            }
            while (iter2.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return operation(defaultValue, iter2.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call it with code like this:

```
char separator = ',';
var first = File.ReadAllLines("firstfile.csv").AsEnumerable();
var second = File.ReadAllLines("secondfile.csv").AsEnumerable();

string defaultValue = "";
int cnt = 0;
if (first.Count() < second.Count())
{
    cnt = first.FirstOrDefault().Split(separator).Length;
}
else
{
    cnt = second.FirstOrDefault().Split(separator).Length;
}
defaultValue = defaultValue.PadLeft(cnt - 1, separator);
var result = first.Merge(second, defaultValue, (f, s) => string.Join(separator.ToString(), f, s));
File.WriteAllLines("combined.csv", result);
```

Note I have added a `char` separator and changed the result of ReadAllLines to give an `IEnumerable<string>` rather than `string[]` to make the code more generic.  Also the above code assumes that the both files have an internally consistent number of columns.

Comment: You sir, are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out which of the two lists is the larger one so you can loop over that one and once you're past the length of the smaller list you can fill up the missing cells with empty values.

Next you need to know how many columns you have in the smaller list as you want to fill these columns with empty values. That means you have to take the header line of the smaller list, split it by comma and count the columns.

Then generate a string containing your empty cells (eg. if your smaller list has 3 columns, you need a string ",," - [String Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) may be of help here).

So then you only have to loop over the larger list and get the two corresponding rows (or use the empty one you generated earlier) and concatenate them with a comma and put them in a list.