# Merge many Lists into one list with properties for each list

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

To show what I want to achieve, I prepared a simplified example:

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
public class SoldProduct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then, somewhere I have a method which gets different lists of `SoldProduct` (from different categories) like this:

```
List<SoldProduct> toolsSold = GetToolSales();
List<SoldProduct> materialsSold = GetMaterialSales();
List<SoldProduct> foodsSold = GetFoodSales();
```

Now, I need to merge them into one list of rows, where a row is something like this:

```
public class SoldProductRow
{
    public SoldProduct ToolSold { get; set; }
    public SoldProduct MaterialSold { get; set; }
    public SoldProduct FoodSold { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:**

So, how to convert these 3 lists into a `List<SoldProductRow>`? Is there some simple, efficient LINQ query? Maybe there is a really simple and efficient way to write it manually?

Let's imagine this row is something like an Excel row; we want to have 2 columns for name and date of tool sales, 2 columns for name and date of material sales, and 2 columns for name and date of food sales.
Essentially list them side by side.

**Difficulties:**

Lists can be of different length, so if we have 3 elements in `toolsSold` but 5 in `materialsSold` and `foodsSold`, then the rows list should have 5 elements (longest list length) where the first 3 elements of the rows list will have all properties, but the 4th and 5th elements should have `null` in `ToolSold` and proper values in `MaterialSold` and `FoodSold`

`List<SoldProduct>` length is usually between 1 and 3, but actually there is `List<Parent>` with possibly hundreds of objects and every parent has 5 `List<SoldProduct>` so, I need to create hundreds of rows.

**Example:**

If I had lists:

```
toolsSold: [
  {Name: hammer, Date:24-09-2020}
]

materialsSold: [
  {Name: wood, Date:23-09-2020},
  {Name: steel, Date:17-08-2020}
]

foodsSold: [
  {Name: apple, Date:07-02-2020}
]
```

I would want this result (2 rows because the longest list has 2 entities):

```
SoldProductsRows: [
  {
     ToolSold: {Name: hammer, Date:24-09-2020}
     MaterialSold: {Name: wood, Date:23-09-2020}
     FoodSold: {Name: apple, Date:07-02-2020}
  },
  {
     ToolSold: null
     MaterialSold: {Name: steel, Date:17-08-2020}
     FoodSold: null
  },
]
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the different lists?  The Product Name?  Or Date?  How do we know what belongs together on a "row" ?

Comment: they have no relation, thats why in row class there is property for each list.

Comment: I added json like example to better show what i want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution without LINQ:

```
int count = Math.Max(Math.Max(toolsSold.Count, materialsSold.Count), foodsSold.Count);

var rowsList = new List<SoldProductRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    rowsList.Add(new SoldProductRow
    {
        ToolSold = toolsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
        MaterialSold = materialsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
        FoodSold = foodsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
    });
}
```

### Steps:

- Use `Math.Max()` to get the count of the longest list.
- Use the [`ElementAtOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netcore-3.1) extension method to get the element of each list at a specific index if it exists; and if not, use `null`.
- Use the values from the previous step to create a new `SolidProductRow` object and add it to the final list.

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/GFLS65982)**.

Comment: Would something like `i < toolsSold.Count ? toolsSold[i] : null` have the same performance as using `.ElementAtOrDefault`, worse performance or better?

Comment: I'll answer you in two points: 1) The performance will be virtually the same because what you proposed is [exactly what `ElementAtOrDefault()` does internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0bd04e5c179c3c7d) when the source is `IList` (e.g., `List<T>` or an array). 2) Whenever you find yourself asking "which is faster", you should go through the list of questions mentioned in [this amazing article](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Why? Because more often than not, the answer to "which is faster" doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ solutions are possible but, as demonstrated in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049932/8967612), a `for` loop looks more readable in this particular case. The simplest LINQ solution I could think of is:

```
var rowsList2 =
    Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(i => new SoldProductRow
    {
        ToolSold = toolsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
        MaterialSold = materialsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
        FoodSold = foodsSold.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
    }).ToList();
```

<sup>..which is basically a disguised loop.</sup>

You could also achieve the same result using a modified "special" version of `Zip()`, but it would be unnecessarily complicated. You may create a reusable generic extension method though if you're going to be using it a lot. Just for fun, I came up with the following method<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipThreeWithDefaults<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    IEnumerable<TThird> third,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult> func)
{
    using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e3 = third.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext())
        {
            var current2 = (e2.MoveNext() ? e2.Current : default(TSecond));
            var current3 = (e3.MoveNext() ? e3.Current : default(TThird));

            yield return func(e1.Current, current2,current3);
        }
        while (e2.MoveNext())
        {
            var current3 = (e3.MoveNext() ? e3.Current : default(TThird));
            yield return func(default(TFirst), e2.Current, current3);
        }
        while (e3.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return func(default(TFirst), default(TSecond), e3.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var rowsList3 = 
    toolsSold.ZipThreeWithDefaults(materialsSold, 
                                   foodsSold, (t, m, f) => new SoldProductRow
    {
        ToolSold = t,
        MaterialSold = m,
        FoodSold = f
    }).ToList();
```

Here's a complete example to [try online](https://rextester.com/NVNL73664).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190703/8967612) by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use LINQ, you could do this:

```
int max = new[] { toolsSold.Count, materialsSold.Count, foodsSold.Count }.Max();
List<SoldProductRow> result = 
    toolsSold.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(null, max - toolsSold.Length))
        .Zip(materialsSold.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(null, max - materialsSold.Length)))
        .Zip(foodsSold.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(null, max - foodsSold.Length)))
        .Select(x => new SoldProductRow
        {
            ToolSold = x.First.First,
            MaterialSold = x.First.Second,
            FoodSold = x.Second
        })
        .ToList();
```